# t-stat for linear regression

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, p-value

I m going a simple linear regression in Matlab using fitlm.

My question is more about the interpretation of the result. I have a t-stat for the full time-serie which is higher than t-stat on smaller subset of this time-serie.

Is that a behavior that could be expected and how to interpret it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your sample size increases, the standard error of your estimate tends to decrease. Survey more people and the margin of error of a poll becomes smaller. Same idea happens with a longer time series.

The t-stat is your estimate divided by the standard error. The smaller the standard error, the larger the t-stat (unless the estimate also converges towards zero).

That's the most obvious story for what's happening.